# Relative links inside jquery tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

see [Fix Broken Links with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331674/fix-broken-links-with-jquery)

I think this is just a chaining/find issue but if I have:

> tab1 - loads /rootdir/dir1/page1.htm with link "page1b.htm"
>   tab2 - loads /rootdir/dir2/page2.htm with link "page2b.htm"

and the page with the tabs on it is /rootdir/tabpage.htm"

So since `jquery` loads all of the pages (fragements) into html into one page and apparently `page1.htm` and `page2.htm` aren't even supposed to haev a `<head>` tag for that reason, how do I fix the broken link problem?

(Since it affects about 50 *more* pages potentially)

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You are having the same issue as the original question.  You need to make the links in your tab documents absolute vs. relative (i.e. `/rootdir/dir1/page1b.htm` vs `page1b.html`

Comment: it is the original question i just hoped to clarify and not have to open 50 pages.  I almost had luck with jquery's for each href type techique